# Two desktop GPU cards, and the second is wrongly identified and unusable

Tags: mining, linux

I've got 2 GPUs inserted into my desktop motherboard:

```
Device 0: Name: AMD Radeon (TM) RX 480 Graphics Address: 10:0
```

This one works, displays and mines OK.

Then:

```
Device 1: Name: AMD Radeon (TM) RX 480 Graphics (POLARIS10, DRM 3.40.0, 5.10.34-1-lts, LLVM 11.1.0) Address: 4294967295:4294967295 Vendor: Intel(R) Corporation Drivers: OpenCL Memory: 4096 MByte Active: false (not selected)
```

In reality this is ASUS Strix RX 470 Gaming. I have 3 of these cards. All of them identifies same. Address seems to be -1 (4294967295). Vendor = Intel? Wahoa?

About STRIX cards: they light up, when I turn-on PC they also starts spinning coolers for a moment. LED on top of them works; LED indication for external power (red = no power; white = power OK) also works on them fine.

When trying to reflash the cards with amdvbflash on my linux system, it sees the first card, that's working; but it does not sees the second card. Also; if I'm trying to use only 1 or 2 STRIX cards; the system beeps saying GPU error. No display output from this card at any conditions, as well.

Could somebody lead me somewhere? Should I check something on the cards themselves?

Thanks.

Comment: That seems more like a hardware issue than a blockchain issue, did try asking for help in hardware forums?

Comment: Yep; can you propose some hardware forums @Ismael? Thanks!

Comment: It is for mining so a better place is reddit.com/r/EtherMining.